# Looking for reverse-engineering UML tool

Tags: c++, uml, reverse-engineering, tool-uml

I'm looking for a reverse-engineering UML free tool for c++ code.
The old software i'm working on has almost no documentation, and i must add an evolution :s
So an UML diagram would help me a lot.

I downloaded StarUML, but when i do the reverse engineering,  i have an issue, it doesn't display all the classes on the diagram, as if it was too small.
I didn't find the solution so i wanted to download another free tool. But doesn't find one.

Thanks for the answers

Adrien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always try Doxygen. It won't produce the most beautiful output of all times, but you can force it to generate class diagrams for you.

Comment: force it ? what do you mean ?

Comment: Doxygen doesn't extract classes if they're not documented, but there are two parameters, `EXTRACT_ALL` and `HIDE_UNDOC` (IIRC) that need to be set to true and false resp. They're both in the same section of the automatically generated config file, so it should be easy to find them.

Comment: Doxygen + GraphVis is the way to go. Set up a Doxygen project, under Diagrams select "Use dot tool from GraphVis package". The class diagrams are actually really good, and are clickable. An example of one I generated: http://tinyurl.com/qzz7dff

Answer (score 1):

One of the best tools I've ever used for reverse engineering to create UML diagrams is Visual Paradigm. I've never used it for C++ but for Java and C#.

Try to take a look:
http://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/vpumluserguide/276/277/7253_reverseengin.html

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice you're asking for a free tool and I talked about it because it's working really great.
During the trial period you can make everything and export/print but with their logo printed on the pages.

Comment: Well, maybe i'll talk about this tool to my boss so we'll buy it. :)
i'll have a free trial first. But today he said "take a free tool"

Comment: That's typical ;) Let me know your impressions.

Comment: My first impression is when i run instant reverse on my project folder  that contains all .h files, i get a buffer overflow :-)

Comment: Yeah. And it barfs on namespaces. Seriously? Can not recommend for this purpose.